# Use Pandas to Find Average Number of Occurrences in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is now just two columns, 'AGE' and 'POPULATION'

I need to find the average age of all of the people.

So I need to add the age value to a list *n* times, where *n* is the population from a given year. If for 2 year olds the population is 5, the number 2 should be added to the list 5 times. Both values are coming out of the Dataframe so I need to iterate through it and use the corresponding values of the same row.

[image: This is a picture of the Dataframe I was Using.]

I was able to get the correct answer with the following code:

```
l = []
for i in ppl_2014['AGE']:
    num = ppl_2014.at['A' + str(i),'POPESTIMATE2014']
    age = ppl_2014.at['A' + str(i),'AGE']

    l += ([age] * num)

avg = sum(l)/len(l)

print(avg)
```

How do I use NumPy or Pandas to do this more efficiently? Even though the answer was right, it took a couple of minutes for the code to run. I assume I need to convert it to a series or dataframe, but I just don't know.

Comment: `np.average(ppl_2014['AGE'], weights=ppl_2014['POPESTIMATE2014'])`

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you should be able to do `df['age'].mean()` (Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html )